# Spring jQuery Autocomplete - Uncaught syntax error

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I was looking at this tutorial (http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-jquery-autocomplete-example/) and trying to implement it in my own Spring project but I am getting a syntax error.

The structure of my project is different to theirs but I can't see what changes would cause the error.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
x.extend.parseJSON @ jquery.1.10.2.min.js:4
$.autocomplete.transformResult @ example:176
g.processResponse @ jquery.autocomplete.min.js:21
(anonymous function) @ jquery.autocomplete.min.js:19
c @ jquery.1.10.2.min.js:4
p.fireWith @ jquery.1.10.2.min.js:4
k @ jquery.1.10.2.min.js:6
r @ jquery.1.10.2.min.js:6
```

Here's my controller:

```
List<Tag> data = new ArrayList<Tag>();

HomeController() {
    data.add(new Tag(1, "ruby"));
    data.add(new Tag(2, "rails"));
    data.add(new Tag(3, "c / c++"));
    data.add(new Tag(4, ".net"));
    data.add(new Tag(5, "python"));
    data.add(new Tag(6, "java"));
    data.add(new Tag(7, "javascript"));
    data.add(new Tag(8, "jscript"));
}

@RequestMapping("/example")
public String showExample(Model model) {

    return "example";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getTags", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Tag> getTags(@RequestParam String tagName) {

    return simulateSearchResult(tagName);

}

private List<Tag> simulateSearchResult(String tagName) {

    List<Tag> result = new ArrayList<Tag>();

    // iterate a list and filter by tagName
    for (Tag tag : data) {
        if (tag.getTagName().contains(tagName)) {
            result.add(tag);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here's my jsp:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

```
<div class="container">
     <div>
        <input type="text"  id="w-input-search" value="">
        <span>
            <button id="w-button-search" type="button">Search</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <script>    
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#w-input-search').autocomplete({
                serviceUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getTags',
                paramName: "tagName",
                delimiter: ",",
                transformResult: function(response) {
                return {
                        suggestions: $.map($.parseJSON(response), function(item) {
                            return { value: item.tagName, data: item.id };
                        })                  
                    };          
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

And my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.spring.web</groupId>
<artifactId>fyp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.37</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? According to the console the error is at this line:

```
suggestions: $.map($.parseJSON(response), function(item) {
```

Comment: What line is the error happening on?

Comment: @MadPhysicist It says 178 which is: suggestions: $.map($.parseJSON(response), function(item) {

Comment: Thanks. Is there a stack trace available?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm not actually getting any errors in eclipse. The page is displaying but when I type in the search form then an error appears on the chrome console.

Comment: Try to see what is returned to the autocomplete by method getTags. Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: As mentioned by @MaximKreschishin above - use your browser's network monitor to see what response `/getTags` returned as it's likely not JSON as it seems to be starting with the "<" character. Notice that your version of the `getTags` method is not annotated with `@ResponseBody`.